# libc-bin:i386 Issue

Tags: apt, dependencies, glibc, glib

Ubuntu Jammy 22.04
I installed for an old game on lutris a new version (2.38) libc-bin:i386 from an external source. Now I destroy the system. I cant remove this package with apt or dpkg and i cant even install or upgrade something new. I need some help, thank you!

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Probieren Sie »apt --fix-broken install«, um dies zu korrigieren.
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 libc-bin:i386 : Hängt ab von: libc6:i386 (> 2.38) aber 2.35-0ubuntu3.4 ist installiert
E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie »apt --fix-broken install« ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).

sudo apt --fix-broken install
Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeiten werden korrigiert … fehlgeschlagen.
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 libc-bin:i386 : Hängt ab von: libc6:i386 (> 2.38) aber 2.35-0ubuntu3.4 ist installiert
E: Fehler: Unterbrechungen durch pkgProblemResolver::Resolve hervorgerufen; dies könnte durch zurückgehaltene Pakete verursacht worden sein.
E: Abhängigkeiten konnten nicht korrigiert werden.
```